# How would you change this Javascript regex to exclude "<br/>"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex `/[^a-z0-9\s]+/ig` . I want the string `<br/>` not to be included in it. How would I edit this to do that?

An example string: `var testContent = "Si mi voz muriera en tierra, <br> llevadla al nivel del mar <br> y dejadla en la ribera. <br>  <br> Llevadla al nivel del mar <br> y nombradla capitana <br> de un blanco bajel de guerra. <br>  <br> Oh mi voz condecorada  <br> con la insignia marinera:  <br> sobre el corazon un ancla  <br> y sobre el ancla una estrella  <br> y sobre la estrella el viento  <br> y sobre el viento una vela!"`

On this string I running this javascript:

```
testContent.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]+/ig, 
                  function ($1) { 
                       return ' ' + $1;
                       }
           ).split(" ");
```

I want this to split at `<br/>` too instead of at `<` and `br` and `/` and `>` when it is that string.

Comment: Right now your regex is matching all capitals and special characters... you want to it match a br as well?

Comment: @Ben Roux no, I want it to not match <br/>

Comment: It's not "included", you only match `</>`. Feel free to give examples of strings that you are working with and exactly what you want from them.

Comment: @Qtax yes, but I want those included, but not when they are in the `<br/>` string.

Comment: @Qtax just added example and more information.

Comment: Show what you want the result to be please.

Comment: Your example contains no `<br />`s!

Comment: @Eric, lol (; @chrome, can you help me understand what you want this whole example code to do? Just get all the words in an array?

Comment: @Qtax @Eric wow, sorry about that, quiet the fail on my part, I guess I meant "<br>". Yes, get all the words in an array.

Comment: @Qtax I want every word, punctuation, and `<br>` seperated into an array

Comment: `so, for.this - you<br>want` an array with this: `so`, `,`, `for`, `.`, `this`, `-`, `you`, `<br>`, `want`? Or did I miss some cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Updated for the following problem (what OP means):

`so, for.this - you<br>want` an array with this: `so`, `,`, `for`, `.`, `this`, `-`, `you`, `<br>`, `want`

You can use something like:

```
var array = testContent.match(/[a-z\d]+|<br\s*\/?>|[^a-z\d\s]+/gi);
```

Will work for both `<br>` and `<br/>` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!.*<br/>.*$)[^a-z0-9\s]+
```

It uses a negative look ahead

EDITED: Corrected neg look ahead syntax.

I admit it: This regex does not work. But I'm working on it!

Comment: The syntax is `(?!...)`, and it will not work like this anyway, eg: `'foo<br/>bar' =~ m§(?!.*<br/>)([^a-z0-9\s]+)§ig` gives you `/>`.

Comment: Only way to make that work would be something nice like `(?:(?!<br/>)(?(?=/>)(?<!<br))(?(?=>)(?<!<br/))[^a-z\d\s])+`, but stuff like this doesn't work in javascript.